# Group generated by some subset

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

(a) Given any group $G$ and a subset $U$, let $\hat{U}$ be the samllest subgroup of $G$ which contains $U$. Prove there is such a subgroup $\hat{U}$ in $G$.

(b) If $gug^{-1}\in U$ for all $g\in G, \ u\in U$, prove that $\hat{U}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

**Proof:** (a) Consider the following family of subgroups of $G$, namely $\mathcal{A}=\{H \text{\ subgroup of}\  G: U\subset H\}$. It is obvious that this family is not empty since $G\in \mathcal{A}$. Let's consider the following intersection and denote it by $\hat{U}$, namely $\hat{U}:= \cap _{H\in \mathcal{A}}H$. The set $\hat{U}$ is a subgroup since the intersection of subgroups is subgroup and it is easy to check that it is the smallest subgroup containing given subset $U$. Thus we have proven the existence of such subgroup.

(b) If $gug^{-1}\in U$ for all $g\in G, \ u\in U$ $\Rightarrow$ $gUg^{-1}\subset U$ and the converse inclusion can be proved the same way. Thus we derived that $gUg^{-1}=U$. We should prove that $\hat{U}$ is normal subgroup of $G$, i.e. for any $g\in G, \ \hat{u}\in \hat{U}$ it is true that $g\hat{u}g^{-1}\in \hat{U}$. In other words, $g\hat{U}g^{-1}\subset \hat{U}.$

Let's take $z\in g\hat{U}g^{-1}$ $\Rightarrow$ $z=g\hat{u}g^{-1}$, where $\hat{u}\in \hat{U}= \cap _{H\in \mathcal{A}}H$ $\Rightarrow$ $\hat{u}\in H$ for any $H\in \mathcal{A}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\hat{u}\in H$ for any $H\subset G$ such that $U\subset H$ $\Rightarrow$ (since $g^{-1}Ug=U$) $\Rightarrow$ $\hat{u}\in H$ for any $H\subset G$ such that $g^{-1}Ug\subset H$ $\Rightarrow$ $\hat{u}\in H$ for any $H\subset G$ such that $U\subset gHg^{-1}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\hat{u}\in g^{-1}(gHg^{-1})g$ for any $gHg^{-1}\subset gGg^{-1}=G$ such that $U\subset gHg^{-1}$ $\Rightarrow$ (denote $\overline{H}=gHg^{-1}$) $\Rightarrow$ $\hat{u}\in g^{-1}\overline{H}g$ for any $\overline{H}\subset G$ such that $U\subset \overline{H}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\hat{u}\in \cap _{\overline{H}\in \mathcal{B}}g^{-1}\overline{H}g$ where $\mathcal{B}=\{\overline{H} \subset G: U\subset \overline{H}\}$.

Also it is easy to prove that $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B}$. Hence, $\hat{u}\in g^{-1}(\cap_{\overline{H}\in \mathcal{B}}\overline{H})g=g^{-1}(\cap_{H\in \mathcal{A}}H)g=g^{-1}\hat{U}g$. Thus, $z=g\hat{u}g^{-1}\in \hat{U}$ we have shown $g\hat{U}g^{-1}\subset \hat{U}$ for any $g\in G$. Thus, $\hat{U}$ is normal in $G$.

Is this proof correct, especially the second part? Would be very grateful for checking out.

Comment: You seem to be using $\Rightarrow$ as an alternative to the word "then" or something like that. This is confusing on its own, it turns the second paragraph of (b) into a thicket of symbols, and just becomes completely incoherent when you have things like $U\subset H\Rightarrow$ (since $g^{-1}Ug=U$) $\Rightarrow\hat u\in H$... Related to the second point, you may want to give the argument some structure and breathing space so each idea in it stands out clearly. Your proof of (a) is fine though modulo a typographical(?) issue with the definition of $\mathcal A$.

Comment: @DerekElkins, i do not understand your remark. Do you think that it is wrong?

Comment: Assuming you're referring to the $\Rightarrow$ stuff, I'm saying using it this way is not common so you should at least explain what you mean by it. It is commonly used for implication, but then it makes no sense in part because implication isn't associative and the scope that each is intended to apply to is unclear. My guess is that you intend $A\Rightarrow B\Rightarrow C$ to mean something like $A\Rightarrow B$ and $B\Rightarrow C$. My real recommendation though is that you not use it this way at all. Just use prose for it. More generally, your proof of (b) is just unreadable currently.

Comment: As an example, the very first sentence of the proof of (b) reads as "if $gug^{-1}\in U$ for all $g\in G$, then $u\in U$ implies $gUg^{-1}=U$" which makes no sense. If you did write out what you presumably intended in a formal notation it would be $(\forall g\in G,u\in U.gug^{-1}\in U)\implies gUg^{-1}=U$. $\implies$ already has the "if" built-in, so saying "if $A\Rightarrow B$" reads as "if $A$ implies $B$" not "if $A$ then $B$". Though, again, just don't use formal logical notation to join together sentence fragments of an informal proof.